# Configure siproxd to use behind a openvpn connection

Tags: proxy, sip

I need to configure a proxy-sip. I discovered siproxd, but I am not able to use it.

My network is as follows:

```
PC-Windows -> Use MicroSip -> 192.168.1.10 
PC-Linux -> Use siproxd -> 
   Network interface -> ens33 -> 192.168.1.111  
   Network interface -> tun0 ->  10.10.2.33 (OpenVPN raised) 
PC-Asterisk -> 10.10.2.222
```

I use this configuration file for siproxd (the other default options)

```
if_inbound  = ens33
if_outbound = tun0
host_outbound = 10.10.2.222
```

In microsip, I configure the Proxy field and put: 192.168.1.111. The other fields I leave them the same as when I have direct access to PC-Asterisk (10.10.2.222) (or when I can use openvpn in this machine)

Microsip connects correctly, but does not allow me to make calls.

What am I doing wrong? Is there another simple alternative that works?

Comment: Could you provide some more information? Like ```ss -ltu; ip a; ip r``` for the linux machine and ```ipconfig /all``` for the windows machines. That would make it easier for us to help.

Comment: I can't. It would have to show confidential information. Apart from the information I have already put ... What other information would be necessary?

Comment: How about blackening the confidential parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per siproxd FAQ ( http://siproxd.sourceforge.net/index.php?op=faq ) ensure that PC-Linux host has packet forwarding enabled ant that iptables is doing masquerading between the two nets.

If PC-Linux host is not PC-Windows default gateway, you would also need to setup static routes to be able to reach the Asterisk network.